# How to integrate the django login system with angular

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, angular-fullstack

I am creating a full stack e-commerce site using `angular` and `rest_framework`. I wanted a login system in it. I have created an API which contains the details of the user model i.e mail, username. I have a profile model too which contains more information about the user i.e products in his/her cart, his/her recent orders. I want that when the user submits the login form he/she the user should be logged in and the details API should get updated.

I searched a lot on the web about it but no article or blog helped me

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: This article is good about authentication https://medium.com/django-rest/django-rest-framework-jwt-authentication-94bee36f2af8 , then you can handle the front end part by sending requests with the JWT you got from django